# How can I get motherboard and CPU Voltage informations in C#?

Tags: c#, hardware

As far as I research on internet, I tried some codes but it's working. it returned '0' value. My question is:How can I get motherboard and CPU Voltage informations in C#?

My code:

```
 //http://wutils.com/wmi/
 //create a management scope object
 ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\ROOT\\cimv2");

 //create object query
 ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM CIM_VoltageSensor");

 //create object searcher
 ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

 //get collection of WMI objects
 ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();

 //enumerate the collection.
 foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection) 
 {
 // access properties of the WMI object
 Console.WriteLine("Accuracy : {0}", m["Accuracy"]);

 }
```

Comment: How about you show us what you tried, as a short but complete program?

Comment: Have you looked into http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/GetHardwareInformation.aspx?

Comment: Have you considered `WqlObjectQuery`? (oh god Jon Skeet saw this, I'm deferring to him)

Comment: @Jon Skeet - I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [OpenHardwareMonitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/) opensource project.

Answer (score 0):

You may find [this](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=17973) helpful. The explanation of the examples are [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/GetHardwareInformation.aspx).

Look into `frmMain.cs` example.